# Apache/PHP fails to start on WinXP when activating MySQL extension

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I've been incrementally setting up a web server for research and testing purposes.  The "server" is running Windows XP and I initially installed Apache Server 2.2 and PHP 5.3.  That's been working great for a while.  I am now needing to setup MySQL which I downloaded and installed MySQL v5.5.  I am able to interact with MySQL via the command-line interface.  In the process of setting up phpMyAdmin, I have encountered difficulties getting PHP and Apache to play nice with MySQL.  Here's what I've discovered and tried:

- In the php.ini file, when I attempt to uncomment either the php_mysql.dll or the php_mysqli.dll extension and restart the Apache server, the server crashes when it starts.  The Windows event viewer says Apache failed to start due to "faulting module php5ts.dll".
- The extension_dir parameter is set to ".\ext" and the php_mysql.dll and php_mysqli.dll files are in that directory.
- I have also tried copying the libmysql.dll file from the lib folder of the MySQL directory to the Windows\System32 directory (with no change in behavior).

I'm at a bit of a loss to figure out what the next step is.  Any suggestions?

Comment: easy way out: copy php_mysqli.dll to your windows dir. Or make your ext-path absolute.

Comment: Well, I thought that the relative path was correct, however, I changed it to an absolute path and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The extension it's looking for is an extension output by php at compile time based on your configured build options. It is not looking for the header files from mysql itself.

Also, ".\ext" is a relative path that may or may not be valid in your installation. You may need to re-compile php to include mysql and mysqli (you should also compile PDO support) into your php build (Or whatever the windows equivalent of re-compiling is).

Also, you should make extension_dir an absolute path not relative.